# Error "Uncaught TypeError: (0 , yup__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.string)(...).name is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, frontend, yup

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , yup__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.string)(...).name is not a function

I got this problem when I was using [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) to validate the form. Here is my code:

```
import * as yup from "yup"

validationSchema:yup.object({
        name:yup.string()
            .name("please input the valid name")
            .required("This field cannot be blank")
            .minLength(3,"Must be at least 3 characters")
            .maxLength(20, "Must be less than 20 chracters"),
})
```

How can I find out the solution?